# Why are class names in com.google.android.play.core obfuscated/minified when I'm not using proguard/R8?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have the following code in my app:

```
val reviewMan = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
Log.d(Plog.LOG_TAG, "created Google Play Review Manager: "+reviewMan.toString())
```

But the message that shows up in the console when I run it is:

> created Google Play Review Manager:
> com.google.android.play.core.review.c@131b84b

This is an *unobfuscated* debug build (the build type's definition in build.gradle contains `minifyEnabled false`) so why doesn't the message say, "created Google Play Review Manager: com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager@131b84b"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the class name `c` in the Google Play library is that the library itself has been minified before it is distributed through Maven.

The `aar` can be found [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0), and the `classes.jar` inside of it already has the minified names.